# Oracle subquery to retrieve data from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, subquery, distinct

I used the following query

```
SELECT 
    a.cluster_cd,
    (SELECT
         Sum(BALANCE_AREA) 
     FROM 
         AGRI.plantation_TRAN p 
     WHERE 
         p.plot_cluster_cd = a.cluster_cd 
         AND trunc(a.agreement_date) = trunc(sysdate) 
         AND a.PLOT_NO = p.PLOT_NO 
         AND a.SEASON_CD = p.SEASON_CD 
         AND (a.SEASON_CD = 10)) as Today,
   (SELECT
        Sum(BALANCE_AREA) 
    FROM 
        AGRI.plantation_TRAN p 
    WHERE 
        p.plot_cluster_cd = a.cluster_cd 
        AND trunc(a.agreement_date) BETWEEN to_date('2014-10-24','YYYY-MM-DD') AND trunc(sysdate) 
        AND a.PLOT_NO = p.PLOT_NO 
        AND a.SEASON_CD = p.SEASON_CD 
        AND (a.SEASON_CD=10)) as Todate
FROM
    AGRI.agreement_TRAN a
```

and I got

```
cluster_cd       Today      Todate
 1               0.8         3.5
 1               2.6         8.2
 2               8.3         9.5
 3               0.2         2.6
 2               6.1         9.1
 3               9.8        11.0
```

But what I need is

today and todate field should be summed for distinct cluster_cd like

```
 Cluster_CD        Today      Todate
   1                123         456
   2                125         789
   3                 45         458
   4                456         789
```

Sum should be made on unique cluster_cd

Comment: I used 'distinct' to cluster_cd, but got differed result.

Comment: Your results make no sense.  Perhaps you should show sample data so it is more apparent how the results are calculated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sum is not grouping on cluster_cd. Please observe cluster_cd, There are duplicate Cluster_cd values. But I need distinct cluster_id values

Comment: @Mallesh can you provide the limited data of two tables mentioned in query that would be more easy to work with for the desired result as shown by you because the result with query and desired result doesn't make any relation.

Comment: @Mallesh please write 'group by p.plot_cluster_cd' in both the inner sub queries and distinct just before the cluster_cd these my help you and you may get your desired result

Comment: find sql fiddle here [link] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05b115/1/0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this :

```
Select cluster_cd,sum(today),sum(Todate) from(

SELECT a.cluster_cd,
(select Sum(BALANCE_AREA) 
FROM AGRI.plantation_TRAN p 
where p.plot_cluster_cd=a.cluster_cd and trunc(a.agreement_date)=trunc(sysdate) and a.PLOT_NO =         p.PLOT_NO AND a.SEASON_CD = p.SEASON_CD AND (a.SEASON_CD=10)) as Today,

(select Sum(BALANCE_AREA) 
FROM AGRI.plantation_TRAN p 
where p.plot_cluster_cd=a.cluster_cd and trunc(a.agreement_date) between to_date('2014-10-
24','YYYY-MM-DD') and trunc(sysdate) and a.PLOT_NO = p.PLOT_NO AND a.SEASON_CD = p.SEASON_CD AND      (a.SEASON_CD=10)) as Todate

from AGRI.agreement_TRAN a)t

group by cluster_cd
```

Comment: Aakanksha by this query you won't get the desired result shown by @Mallesh in the question

Comment: @DharmeshPorwal - Yes, since the values dont make any sense, i thought he just wrote it to fill the table .

Comment: i think you have to read the third comment given by mallesh down the question

Comment: See the last line of the question : "Sum should be made on unique cluster_cd"

Comment: @DharmeshPorwal : and thats why i voted up ur comment :)

Comment: @AakankshaShah Thanks a lot. Its working!! Thank you Dharmesh Porwal

Answer (score 0):

This query may help:

```
SELECT a.cluster_cd,
       sum(case when a.agreement_date >= trunc(sysdate) then nvl(BALANCE_AREA, 0) else 0 end) as Today,
       sum(case when a.agreement_date < trunc(sysdate) then nvl(BALANCE_AREA, 0) else 0 end) as Todate
FROM AGRI.agreement_TRAN a
     LEFT JOIN AGRI.plantation_TRAN p
     ON (p.plot_cluster_cd = a.cluster_cd
         and a.PLOT_NO = p.PLOT_NO 
         and a.SEASON_CD = p.SEASON_CD
        )
WHERE a.agreement_date between to_date('2014-10-24000000','YYYY-MM-DDHH24MISS') 
                           and trunc(sysdate)+1-1/24/60/60
  AND a.SEASON_CD=10
GROUP BY a.cluster_cd;
```